# Adding SASL Auth in IRC Bot

Tags: lua, bots, irc, sasl, lua-5.1

How could i add sasl authentication on my Lua 5.1 IRC Bot?
Right now it sends a message to Nickserv to identify.

Is there any way at all to add SASL authentication?
I use the lua socket module to connect to IRC.
The complete source can be found at https://github.com/wolfy1339/Wolfybot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully support SASL you must first support [CAP IRC extensions](http://ircv3.net/specs/core/capability-negotiation-3.1.html), and then SASL AUTH PLAIN.

You can find documentation on these via the IRCv3 specifications: http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/sasl-3.1.html

`CAP LS` is used to determine if SASL is supported by the network, then once you have enabled it via `CAP REQ`, you can send `AUTH PLAIN` with your base64 encoded username and password.

IMPORTANT SECURITY NOTE: Make sure you also use SSL, as `AUTH PLAIN` offers NO security and BLOWFISH etc are not gauranteed to be portable to different services packages!